# Problem with a Golang webapp and system service

Tags: linux, go, systemd

I am trying to create a Golang server using the gin framework on ubuntu. It works fine when it is executed in the terminal after building it with go build and equally works well locally.

Systemd

```
Description=goapp

[Service]
Type=simple
Restart=always
RestartSec=5s
ExecStart=/home/.../goapp/main


[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I got this error

```
goapp.service - rediate
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/goapp.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2022-09-29 08:14:10 UTC; 66ms ago
Process: 21628 
ExecStart=/home/.../go/goapp/main (code=exited, status=2)
Main PID: 21628 (code=exited, status=2)
CPU: 9ms
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because From the tag: systemd questions should be for *programming questions* using systemd or its libraries. Questions about *configuring the daemon* (including writing unit files) are better directed to Unix & Linux: https://unix.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a working directory to the systemd fix this error.

```
Description=goapp

[Service]
Type=simple
Restart=always
RestartSec=
WorkingDirectory=/home/.../goapp
ExecStart=/home/.../goapp/main


[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Answer (score 2):

Go is compiled language. You need to build your code into an executable binary file using `go build` command and then give path to binary file to systemd via  `ExecStart` property in unit file.

See [Go Documentation](https://go.dev/doc/) and specifically [Compile and install the application](https://go.dev/doc/tutorial/compile-install) section to find out more about how to compile your application.

In your example you have `ExecStart=/home/.../goapp/main.go` which is telling systemd to run source code file. That file is not executable and understood by operating system so it fails to execute and systemd unit fails because of that.

Comment: Thanks @blami; my mistake (main not main. go); I did build the code prior; the error is for main executable.

Comment: Can you add output of `journalctl -u goapp.service` ? It seems your app is exiting straight when run instead of running and serving requests. Also might be worth to add some logging in case of errors in you Go code to easier troubleshoot why it exits.